# google-dfp enable lazy loading only on certain ads

Tags: google-dfp

I am using google-dfp's lazyLoading. When this is enabled, all Ads are lazy loaded. Is there a way to enable it only for specific ads and not for all?

```
googletag.pubads().enableLazyLoad({
    // Fetch slots within 6 viewports.
    fetchMarginPercent: 500,
    // Render slots within 1.04 viewports.
    renderMarginPercent: 4,
    // Double the above values on mobile, where viewports are smaller
    // and users tend to scroll faster.
    mobileScaling: 10,
});
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to have custom lazyloading settings per ad, though I wish there was as I need this functionality myself. Right now I'm using Intersection Observer to monitor position on certain ad slots to manually load/refresh them, on top of GAM's native lazyloading config to get what I need. This may be your only option for now.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for confirming my suspection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing it by splitting your adrequests in 2 batchs :

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  // Define ad slots.
  var slots = [
    googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe', [728, 90], 'slot-1')
             .addService(googletag.pubads()),
    googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe', [728, 90], 'slot-2')
             .addService(googletag.pubads()),
    googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe', [300, 250], 'slot-3')
             .addService(googletag.pubads()),
    googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe', [300, 250], 'slot-4')
             .addService(googletag.pubads()),
    googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe', [300, 250], 'slot-5')
             .addService(googletag.pubads())
  ];

  // Disable initial load to precisely control when ads are requested.
  googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();

  // Enable SRA and services.
  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.enableServices();

  // Issue first SRA request (slots 1 and 2) immediately.
  googletag.pubads().refresh([slots[0], slots[1]]);

  // Enable lazyLoading after 1st SRA batch
  googletag.pubads().enableLazyLoad({
      // Fetch slots within 6 viewports.
      fetchMarginPercent: 500,
      // Render slots within 1.04 viewports.
      renderMarginPercent: 4,
      // Double the above values on mobile, where viewports are smaller
      // and users tend to scroll faster.
      mobileScaling: 10,
  });

  // Issue second SRA request (slots 3, 4 and 5) once lazyLoading has been enabled
  googletag.pubads().refresh([slots[2], slots[3], slots[4]]);

});
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/control-sra-batching) for details about SRA batching.